# Audio - Chrome Mobile - Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

I cannot play audio with Chrome Mobile on Android. Is it restricted from playing audio (OGG)?

So, I've an HTML document. Inside, is the following audio tag:

```
<audio id="audiotag1" src="beep.ogg" preload="auto"></audio>
```

I also trigger the audio to play with JS:

```
 document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
```

The audio plays fine in Chrome desktop but doesn't play at all in Chrome Mobile. Are there some restrictions/flags I should know?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome for Android requires a user-gesture to play the sound audio file.  Make sure that your `play` invocation is on an event such as click.

Answer (score 0):

Yes only Mozilla I believe really support that format on mobile